# IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jsp, exceção, tomcat, catalina

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma aplicação web simples (JSP / Servlets), que ao iniciar no Tomcat 8.5.16, não "roda" e envia seguinte mensagem no catalina.out:

```
INFO [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:986)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:96)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Utilizo as versões:

Java: 1.8.0_181

MySQL: 5.7.24

JDBC Driver: 8.0.12

SO: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Não estou usando o eclipse, coloco o .war direto na pasta WebApps.
Estranho que uma segunda aplicação, com os mesmos jar's e configurações roda normalmente.

Com essa aplicação, começa a gerar algumas tabelas, para e manda a mensagem acima.
Alguém teria alguma ideia do que possa ser esse problema?

Comment: Remova o war da pasta, coloque novamente e reinicie o Tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resoluçao:

Removi o tomcat do computador (todo ele, sua pasta toda!).
Fiz o download novamente, coloquei o war e funcionou.

Antes de fazer isso, já tinha tentando remover só o war, colocar lib's dentro da pasta do tomcat, etc... Nada resolveu.

Obrigado!